# Why is eleventy trying to parse a file in a passthrough copy?

Tags: javascript, liquid, eleventy

I added a "scripts" folder as a [passthrough copy](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/copy/) to my Eleventy site and installed some npm dependencies inside it for scripts to be run on the page load.

So my .eleventy.js has some lines like this:

```js
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("img");
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("scripts");
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("css");
```

But when I run `npx eleventy`, I get a build error that says,

```
Language does not exist: sh
Problem writing Eleventy templates: (more in DEBUG output)
> Having trouble rendering liquid (and markdown) template ./scripts/wb-service-worker/node_modules/bs-fetch/README.md
```

Why is it trying to "render liquid" in a passthrough copy? (I thought the whole point of passthrough copies is it *doesn't* try to parse them.) How do I get it to stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addPassthroughCopy` will copy the files through without parsing, but if the file is also in the input directory, eleventy will process it in its normal way too.

You should keep the assets that you want to be passthrough-copied in a seperate folder to the src files that you are inputting to eleventy for processing.

---

See these docs for more help:

- [Input Directory](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/config/#input-directory)
- [Ignoring Files](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/ignores/)
- [Passthrough's handling of input files](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/copy/#how-passthrough-file-copy-handles-input-directories)